# C# WPF вылет приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

На компьютере стояла Windows 7, было произведено обновление до 10. Перестали запускаться приложения WPF.

Проверил, пустое консольное приложение нормально запускается, а новое WPF приложение вылетает после появления окна.

В чем может быть проблема?

---

Дополнение:

> Приложение: LoadOptRE.exe
>   Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
>   Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
>   Сведения об исключении: System.EntryPointNotFoundException
>      в MS.Internal.UIAutomationTypes.Interop.OSVersionHelper.IsWindows10RS3OrGreater()
>      в MS.Internal.UIAutomationTypes.Interop.OSVersionHelper..cctor()
>   Сведения об исключении: System.TypeInitializationException
>      в MS.Internal.Automation.AutomationIdentifierConstants..cctor()

И далее еще больше исключений по System.TypeInitializationException

Comment: Приложите текст ошибки

Comment: На компьютере на котором стоит windows 10 и наблюдается данная ошибка отсутствует студия чтобы узнать точную причину ошибки. Выскакивает стандартное окошко о прекращении работы приложения

Comment: Текст исключения должен попадать в журнал событий windows https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Журнал_событий

Comment: Добавил текст исключение

Comment: Это ваше приложение, или не запускаются _все_ WPF-приложения?

Comment: Возможно, разработчики приложения по глупости применили к своему коду ngen, и не обновили образ при смене версии OS.

Comment: А не использует-ли приложение p/invoke? И после обновления Windows какая-нибудь сторонняя библиотека поменяла API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить .Net, например

Comment: да именно это и помогло